# Error in use PostGIS SQL function with two select statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I am new to PostGIS and SQL with a lot of things I need to learn.

I tried this SQL query:

```
Select ST_AsText(Select line from pathway1f)
```

I got errors.

```
Select line from pathway1f
```

This query works fine; thousands of lines are returned.

I want to decode the query result using `ST_AsText()`.

It seems like I can't use two select statements. What's the correct syntax?

Comment: Sounds like you need to solve 2 problems. One, format the query like `select ST_AsText(line) from pathway1f` to fix that problem, second, you are going to get all rows returned to which you will need to append a WHERE clause to this query to filter rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the geometry column name directly

```
Select ST_AsText(line)
from pathway1f;
```